# Use of the くれた with ようとする in this sentence

Tags: reading-comprehension, giving-and-receiving

> あんな遠回しに嬉しさを伝えようとしてくれていたのもそうだが、ちゃんと食べてくれたのを見ると作った甲斐があったというものだ。

Context: The character made a bento for their friend and got them to eat it.
ちゃんと食べてくれたのを見ると作った甲斐があったというものだ。

The second part is saying that watching said friend eating made him feel making it was worth, but I don't quite get the first part

あんな遠回しに嬉しさを伝えようとし

This roundabout way to attempt to deliver joy? What is くれていたのもそうだが saying?